# SPF + DMARC pass anf DKIM fails

Tags: email, smtp, web-hosting, vps, mail-server

I have a problem when sending a message via mail.mydomain.com, it sends the message to spam emails, and I don’t know why I used tools to check the DNS, such as mxtoolbox, and the SPF, DKIM, and DMARC did not have any problem, but when I send a message, it is for Gmail. He gives me
SPF: PASS with IP 31.220.31.138 Learn more
DKIM: 'FAIL' with domain theopgate.com Learn more
DMARC: 'PASS' Learn more
I don't know why, and this is the DNS record for my domain
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28C8K.png)
I use webuzo control panel
Hostinger
My domain

theopgate.com

Answer (score 0):

DKIM cannot be properly checked based on the DNS records alone, for example in the case of a configuration error or selector/key mismatch in the mailserver DKIM implementation. What you could do is send an email from a mailbox on your own domain to `ping@tools.mxtoolbox.com`. You will get back a reply in which you can see more details about DKIM selector used and signature verification. That might help you to track down the DKIM failure that Google reports.

See https://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability for more details about this check.

**Edit:**
Saw there is some whitespace in the public key inside the TXT record. I'm not sure if this is explicitly allowed or forbidden according to the spec, but it might be best avoided altogether.
[whitespace in TXT record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yidq1.png)

Comment: I see that he did not give me any error, it is all correct

Comment: Next attempt, you could check the headers from the message that arrived to your spam folder. There are some online tools that can help you to verify a DKIM signature.

Something else I noticed in your DKIM record, though MXToolbox says it's valid, is that there are line breaks between the different lines in your public key. I'm not deep enough into the spec to say if it's allowed or forbidden, but maybe Google mailservers are sensitive to it. I cannot add a screenshot here so will update my original answer with it.

Comment: I check all and  all right and all pass to gmail but still go to spam folder